# Creating a Maybe type in Raku

Tags: types, raku

I have a lot of functions that can fail, but also have a return type defined in their signature. Since I like defining the types of variables whenever possible, I want to define a Maybe subset to use for this. What I came up with is this:

```
subset Maybe is export of Mu where Mu | Failure;
```

The problem with this is `Failure` is a subclass of `Mu`, so this will match anything and everything, when what I really want is to be able to match one specific type along with `Failure` dynamically. My next thought was to create a parameterized role to use as a type, since I don't want to create subsets for every single type that could also be a `Failure`. I imagine it looking something like this:

```
role Maybe[::T] {
    # ...
}

sub foo(--> Int) { rand < 0.5 ?? 1 !! fail 'oops' }

my Maybe[Int] $foo = foo;
```

Only I have no clue what I'd need to add to the role in order to make this work. Is it possible to create a role like this? If not, is there another way I could create a type to do what I want?

Answer (score 10):

Perl6 types are already Maybe types.

It's just that Perl6 has typed nulls unlike most other languages with Maybe types.

---

This is `Maybe[Int]` variable:

```perl6
my Int $a;
my Int:_ $a; # more explicit
```

This holds a definite `Int`:

```perl6
my Int:D $a = …; # must be assigned because the default is not “definite”
```

This holds a null `Int`:

```perl6
my Int:U $a;
```

---

Note that `Failure` is a subtype of `Nil`, so even subroutines that have a return type specified can return them.
(`Nil` is not like `null` or `nil` from other languages.)

```perl6
sub foo ( --> Int:D ) { Bool.pick ?? 1 !! fail 'oops' }

my $foo = foo; # $foo contains the failure object
```

`Nil` is really a type of generic soft failure. When assigned to a variable it just resets it to the default.

```perl6
my Int $foo = 1;

$foo = Nil;

say $foo.perl; # Int
```

```perl6
my Int:D $bar is default(42) = 1;

$bar = Nil

say $bar.perl; # 42
```

The typical default is the same as the type.

```perl6
my Int $foo;

say $foo.VAR.default.perl; # Int
```

A specific soft failure would be to return a type object

```perl6
sub foo ( --> Int ){
  Bool.pick ?? 1 !! Int
}
```

That is why I said `Nil` is a “*generic*” soft failure.

---

Generally if you are defining the type of a variable, you want it to be of that type. So your code should complain immediately if it gets something of another type.

There are better ways to deal with a `Failure`.

```perl6
sub foo(--> Int:D ) { rand < 0.5 ?? 1 !! fail 'oops' }

with foo() -> Int:D $foo {
  … # use $foo here
} else -> $fail {
  … # use $fail here
}
```

This works because `Failure` always sees itself as being undefined.

You can also use that with `when`

```perl6
given foo() {
  when Int:D -> Int:D $foo {
    … # use $foo here
  }
  when Failure:D -> Failure:D $fail {
    # a DEFINITE Failure value
    # (`DEFINITE` is different than `defined`.)
  }
  default {
    … # handle unexpected values (can be removed if not needed)
  }
}
```

Or just the defined-or operator `//` if you don't care what kind of failure it is.

```perl6
my Int:D $foo = foo() // 1;
```

You may even want to use that to turn a `Failure` into a `Nil`.

```perl6
my Int:D $foo is default(42) = foo() // Nil;
```

---

If you really want a maybe-failure subset, I think this should work:

```perl6
sub Maybe-Failure ( Any:U ::Type ) {
  anon subset :: of Any where Type | Failure
}

my constant Maybe-Int = Maybe-Failure(Int);

# note that the type has to be known at compile-time for this line:
my Maybe-Int $foo = foo;
```

It doesn't currently work though.

(Note that you should not be dealing with `Mu` unless you need to specifically deal with the types and values that are outside of the `Any` type; like `Junction` and `IterationEnd`.)

Something else that should probably also work is:

```perl6
my class Maybe-Failure {
  method ^parameterize ( $, Any:U ::Type ) {
    anon subset :: of Any where Type | Failure
  }
}

my Maybe-Failure[Int] $foo;
```

This seems like it fails for the same reason the other one does.

---

Another way would be to create a new type of class like `subset`.
That is `subset` uses a different MOP than the rest of the classes in Perl6.

Comment: This is a good explanation of different ways to deal with failures, but I was looking for a way to define a type for what may be a `Failure` that I could use when assignin the return value of a function that can fail to a variable before handling it properly. That way, my code could be a little more terse

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR See @Kaiepi's own answer for a solution. But every non-native type in P6 is already automatically an enhanced nullable type that's akin to an enhanced Maybe type. So that needs to be discussed too. To help structure my answer I'm going to pretend it's [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) even though it isn't.

## Solving Y

> I want to define a `Maybe subset` to use for this

See @Kaiepi's answer.

## All non-native P6 types are already akin to Maybe types

The `subset` solution is overkill for what [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) defines as a Maybe type which boils down to:

> `None` [or] the original data type

It turns out that all non-native P6 types are already something akin to an enhanced Maybe type.

The enhancement is that the (P6 equivalent of a) `None` knows what original data type it's been paired with:

```
my Int $foo;
say $foo        # (Int) -- akin to an (Int) None
```

## Solving X

> I have a lot of functions that can fail, but also have a return type defined in their signature.

As you presumably know, unless [`use fatal;`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pragmas#fatal) is in effect, P6 deliberately allows routines to return failures even if there's a return type check that doesn't explicitly allow them. (A `subset` return type check can explicitly reject them.)

So given that a return type check `Foo` is automatically turned into something akin to a `subset` with a `where Failure | Foo` clause, it's understandable that you thought to accommodate that by creating an matching subset so you could accept the result when assigning to a variable.

But as is hopefully clear from the earlier discussion, it may be better to make use of the built in aspect of P6's type system that's akin to Maybe types.

A [`Nil`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Nil) may be used to indicate what's called a *benign* failure. So the following works to indicate failure (as you wish to do in some of your routines) *and* set a receiving variable to a `None` (or rather the enhanced P6 equivalent of one):

```
sub foo (--> Int) { Nil }
my Int $bar = foo;
say $bar; # (Int)
```

So one option is that you replace calls to `fail` with `return Nil` (or just `Nil`).

One could imagine a [pragma](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pragmas) (called, say, `failsoft`) that demotes all `Failure`s to benign failure `Nil`s:

```
use failsoft;
sub foo (--> Int) { fail }
my Int $bar = foo;
say $bar; # (Int)
```

## Nullable types

The wikipedia introduction about Maybe types also says:

> A distinct, but related concept ... is called *nullable types* (often expressed as `A?`).

The closest P6 equivalent to the `Int?` syntax used by some languages to express a nullable `Int` is simply `Int`, without the question mark. The following are valid type constraints:

- `Int` -- P6 equivalent of a nullable `Int` or a `Maybe Int`
- `Int:D` -- P6 equivalent of a non-nullable `Int` or a `Just Int`
- `Int:U` -- P6 equivalent of an `Int` null or an `(Int) None`

([`:D` and `:U`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#Constraining_argument_definiteness) are called type smilies for an obvious reason. :))

Continuing, [wikipedia's *Nullable types* page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type) says:

> In statically-typed languages, a *nullable type* is [a Maybe] type (in functional programming terms), while in dynamically-typed languages (where *values have types, but variables do not*), equivalent behavior is provided by having *a single null value*.

In P6:

- Values have types -- but so do variables.
- P6 types are akin to an enhanced `Maybe` type (as explained above) or an enhanced nullable type where there are as many `None`s or "null" values as there are types instead of having just a single `None` or null value.

(So, is P6 a statically typed language or a dynamically typed language? It's actually [Beyond static **vs** dynamic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4EF9FOOpQg&list=PLRuESFRW2Fa77XObvk7-BYVFwobZHdXdK&index=104&t=0s) and is instead static **and** dynamic.)

Continuing:

> Primitive types such as integers and booleans cannot generally be null, but the corresponding nullable types (nullable integer and nullable boolean, respectively) can also assume the `NULL` value.

In P6, all non-native types (like the arbitrary precision `Int` type) are akin to enhanced Maybe/nullable types.

In contrast, all [native types](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativetypes) (like `int` -- all lowercase) are non-nullable types -- what wikipedia is calling primitive types. They cannot be null or `None`:

```
my int $foo;
say $foo;    # 0
$foo = int;  # Cannot unbox a type object (int) to int
```

Finally, returning to the wikipedia `Maybe` page:

> The core difference between [maybe] types and nullable types is that [maybe] types support nesting `(Maybe (Maybe A) ≠ Maybe A)`, while nullable types do not `(A?? = A?)`.

P6's built in types don't support nesting in this way without use of subsets. So a P6 type, while *akin* to an enhanced `Maybe` type, is really just an enhanced nullable type.

Comment: Good point about what I was calling `Maybe` not actually being `Maybe` by definition

Comment: I think the explanation's better now. With the Solving X section, while I can see how returning `Nil` would be better than failing in certain cases, for what I was writing when I asked the question it doesn't. I use failure messages to notify users of the program when something goes wrong, and for some routines, I let their exception get thrown in certain places they're used when failing is unacceptable, but not for other places where it'd make more sense to deal with them in other ways.

Answer (score 7):

[Brad Gilbert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55079804/9574771) pointed me in the right direction, particularly:

> Another way would be to create a new type of class like subset.
>   That is subset uses a different MOP than the rest of the classes in Perl6.

The solution I came up with is this:

```
use nqp;

class Maybe {
    method ^parameterize(Mu:U \M, Mu:U \T) {
        Metamodel::SubsetHOW.new_type:
            :name("Maybe[{T.^name}]"),
            :refinee(nqp::if(nqp::istype(T, Junction), Mu, Any)),
            :refinement(T | Failure)
    }
}

my Maybe[Int] $foo = 1;
say $foo; # OUTPUT: 1
my Maybe[Int] $bar = Failure.new: 2;
say $bar.exception.message; # OUTPUT: 2
my Maybe[Int] $baz = 'qux'; # Throws type error
```

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try the new Definitely::Maybe module [here](https://raku.land/zef:masukomi/Definitely)